# GRAILS and DOJO data binding issue

Tags: grails, dojo

Using Grails 1.3.5 and Dojo 1.3.5

```
class A
{
    B b
}
```

gsp code...

```
<g:select name="a.b" from="${B.list()}" optionKey="id"  dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="someId"/>
```

grails controller code...

Grails is suposed to bind all the data to my domain class after:

```
     A a = new A(params)
```

but, aparently there is some issue with Dojo Combo 'cause the data-binding is NOT working 
However if I do this instead it works (the data is correctly binded) :

```
<g:select name="a.b" from="${B.list()}" optionKey="id"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that's eventually generated from that first `g:select`?  Also, define "not working" - empty ComboBox?  No widget?  What's (not) happening?

Comment: The comboBox is filled. The problem is in my opinion that Grails cant do data-binding with Dojo Combo Box

Comment: <input id="someid" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" waistate="haspopup-true,autocomplete-list" wairole="textbox" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" dojoattachevent="onkeypress:_onKeyPress,compositionend" autocomplete="off" name="a.b" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" value="THE VALUE IS PRESENT...">

Answer (score 0):

If you need b.id in controller you can use FilteringSelect:

```
<g:select name="b" from="${B.list()}" optionKey="id"  dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" data-dojo-props="name: 'b'" id="someId"/>
```

In this case you will get `params.b == b.id` and rest is on your side.

*Regards
Mateusz*